# Pass prop using router-view and Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a Laravel Blade page that calls a Vue page using router-view. I have a "test" prop on the Vue page, but the page is not receiving the prop.

```
const routes = [
    {path: '/:test', component: MainPageIndex, name: 'mainPageIndex', props: true}
];
```

The code on the Blade page is:

```
<router-view name="mainPageIndex" :test="Test message"> </router-view>
<router-view :test="Test message"> </router-view>
```

Comment: Did you declare `test` props on Vue component?

Comment: yes, sure, it’s declared.

Comment: Did you try `test="Test Message"` instead of `:test="Test message"`?

Comment: Thanks! It worked now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 types of properties: static and dynamic.

- static: test="some message" (for static values)
- dynamic: v-bind:test="variable" (for computed values or objects etc.)

In your case, you should use the static one

```
test="some message"
```

Comment: It's not so much static vs dynamic as string vs javascript expression.